# How to stop the notification Audio?

Tags: iphone

Iam doing one application in that i used the notification and assign the sound name.And my requirment is when the notification occur i touch the screen and stop the notification sound.SO for this how to develope the code.please guide me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to stop the sound. The notification is handled by the iOS and not your app.